# create new column based on existing pattern R

Tags: r, extract

I have this

```
tableRules <- as.data.table(data.frame(object_name = c("instr_asset_row","functional_cat","ref_sector_second")))

listDimPoss <- c("instr_asset","ref_sector","functional_cat")
```

I want to create a new column in tableRules: tableRules$DIMENSION
that will check in tablerules$object_name if the value includes the patterns listed in listdimPoss.
If yes, then I want the value of tableRules$Rimension to be the pattern listed in listDimPoss.
so here I want as a results

```
tableRules$DIMENSION <- c("instr_asset","functional_cat","ref_sector")))
```

Comment: this question has no relevance to include 'design-patterns' tag!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `regex_left_join`

```
library(data.table)
library(fuzzyjoin)
regex_left_join(tableRules,  data.table(DIMENSION = listDimPoss), 
     by = c("object_name" = "DIMENSION"))
        object_name      DIMENSION
1   instr_asset_row    instr_asset
2    functional_cat functional_cat
3 ref_sector_second     ref_sector
```